# Format Census ACS API Data For Use In Choropleth Map

Tags: javascript, api, d3.js, census

I am using the US Census ACS [API](http://www.census.gov/developers/) to extract data for all counties in the US. I then want to generate a county-level choropleth map shaded based on the values. If I have a static data file (a CSV with area code: value) I am able to render the data. But, the data from the API comes back as:

```
0: "B08101_025E"
1: "NAME"
2: "state"
3: "county"
...
0: "42"
1: "Autauga County, Alabama"
2: "01"
3: "001"
```

The data appears to be needed in :value such that the above would look like (ignoring header element):

```
01001: 42
```

I think I am getting mixed up in the formatting of the data and what the expected output should be. In the end, what I am doing is this:

```
    var pad = d3.format("05d"),
    quantize = d3.scale.quantile().domain([0, 15]).range(d3.range(9));

    d3.json("us-counties.json", function (json) {
        counties.selectAll("path")
        .data(json.features)
        .enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("class", function (d) {
            return "q" + quantize(dataSet[pad(d.id)]) + "-9";
        })
        .attr("d", path)
        .on("click", click)
        .append("svg:title")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.properties.name + ": " + dataSet[pad(d.id)] + "%";
        });
    });
```

This is taken from [here](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/choropleth.html). Notice that `dataSet[pad(d.id)]` has no hits because the data is not in a key/value pair I think it needs. How to get this in the expected format? I have tried just making the `dataSet` be a 2d array:

```
0: "01001"
1: 42
```

This still does not have the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like it helps to ask the question. After that I walked through the problem one more time and did this:

```
    var dataObj = {};
            d3.json(jsonRequest, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    if (key > 0) {
                        var apiValue = parseInt(val[0], 10);
                        var apiState = val[2];
                        var apiCounty = val[3];
                        //var elmentArray = [apiState + apiCounty, apiValue];
                        //dataSet.push(elmentArray);
                        dataObj[apiState + apiCounty] = apiValue;
                    }
                });
...
 return d.properties.name + ": " + dataObj[pad(d.id)] + "%";
```

The only issue now is that the data does not get updated when I change the data source.

Comment: You could simply reset `dataObj` to be empty and do the conversion again when switching to a new data source.

Comment: It is already reset. The `dataObj` gets updated but the code that uses the `dataObj` doesnt seem to get fired (it is in the showData() function block just after the setting of dataObj loop).

Comment: Well you could call it explicitly.

Comment: Turns out it is not actually updating the svg. Trying to destroy SVG and then reapply is creating interesting artifacts - multiple SVGs appearing on the page. Ah well, back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

The [acs package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/acs/) for R is another useful way to obtain ACS data (via the API, but friendly).

Also there was useful, extensive discussion of using R (including the acs package) to create color-coded maps from Census data, with examples, here:

http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/choropleth-map-r-challenge.html

and

http://eglenn.scripts.mit.edu/citystate/tag/acs/

and

https://gist.github.com/hadley/233134